# Seat booking workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a seat booking spreadsheet for a show that i'm managing at university. I have a list of all the seats available with one row per seat and a list saying how many seats each customer has requested.

Is there any way that I can make a macro that finds a block of empty seats and pastes the name of a customer who wants that many seats in to each cell in the block?

Comment: I have not tried it but I believe you could colour the empty and booked seats differently and search for a cell of the “empty” colour. You would then have to check the following cells to ensure you have a block of the right size. Possible but messy. Why this approach? When I buy tickets for a show, I am shown an image of the auditorium showing booked and empty seats so I can point and say “I will have those three.”

Comment: @TonyDallimore that's what i've got at the moment, but with an auditorium of 300 seats to cover for 4 nights of our show, that's quite time consuming and as you said, messy.
In an ideal world we would use an online booking system like you've mentioned, but we're a small university society so we just don't have the funds to pay the premium that ticketing companies ask for for the use of these features.

Comment: I understand you want a simple, cheap system. Your question implies you want to allocate seats without consulting the customer.  Is that the current system with some operator typing the names into each cell individually.  How does that work?  Some people want to be at the front, some at the back and some on the left.  Don't they get to choose from amid the remaining seats?

Comment: @Tony Dallimore Yeah, we're not offering people a choice of seats, but we have to be able to provide a list of where everyone is sitting for our university health and safety officer. It's just easier if we know where each person is sitting before the show, otherwise we'd have to write it down on the door, which makes taking tickets on the night slow!

At the moment, I have one sheet listing how many seats people have requested and another sheet listing all of the seats in the auditorium. I'm manually typing in each persons name to a block of seats that fits heir booking request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed some test data so I envisaged an auditorium like this:

[image: Auditorium]

I have a solid block in the middle with wings that fan out at the side.  At the back I have spaces for wheel chair users.  I do not recall ever seeing a theatre or auditorium for which every floor is not a variation on this theme.  I also do not recall a seat numbering system that was not <floor><letter><number>.  I have not handled multiple floors.  I am hoping this is sufficiently close to your auditorium for you to be saying to yourself: “Yes: I could adapt that to my needs.”

It sounds as though you need this system today.  I remember a cartoon: “Of course I need it today.  If I needed it tomorrow, I would have asked for it tomorrow.”  So I am going for simple rather than elegant.

I was taught that the secret to a good program is a good data model.  One seat per row is not, in my view, a good data model.  I think I could make it work but the code would be complex and confusing.  My data model will start with the ranges: A3-A13, B3-B13, C4-C14 and so on.  I found typing all these ranges difficult; I kept getting muddled up.  So I switched to an unused worksheet and typed the first two columns and used a formula to create the third column:

[image: Build ranges]

I will explain the strange sequence in a moment.  You may be better at typing ranges than I am and therefore not need this intermediate step.

I then copied the **values** from column 3 to worksheet “Available” to create:

[image: Available before macro has been run]

I have named the four days Monday to Thursday.  You can use any four strings providing they are different.  I have divided the seats into two types: “Regular” and “Wheel chair user”.  You could have one price for rows at the front and another for rows at the back or any other division that may be appropriate.  You need a column per day per division and a name for each division.  There have to be separate columns because the seats in each division are allocated independently.

I promised to explain the strange sequence.  With one exception (explained below), all of the seats in the first row will be allocated before any seats in the second row.  I have decided that I want to fill the first four rows in the middle section before I start using the seats in the wings.  Because the system starts at the top and works down, you can control the sequence in which ranges are allocated.  You may not need that functionality but it is there for free if you do.

The exception to filling A3-A13 before considering B3-B13 is because you do not want odd seats at the end of rows.  I assume most bookings are for couples with the occasion singleton, threesome and so on.  If a booking means A12 would be filled but not A13, that booking will be allocated to the B3-B13 block.  The final seats in block A3-A13 will only be filled with a booking that matches the remaining seats unless no better option exists.

You say you have “a list saying how many seats each customer has requested.”  I have generated some random bookings to get:

[image: New bookings before macro is run]

If your current list has merged given and family names, we will have the problem of splitting then because I really believe we need them separate.  The “Day” and “Part” correspond to the column headings in worksheet “Available”.  By combining these values, the system knows which column is appropriate for this booking.  Most of the test bookings are for two seats with a sprinkling of ones, threes and fours.  One booking is for fourteen seats which the system will not be able to handle.  In my experiences, large groups are given matching seats in adjacent rows (for example: A3-A9 and B3-B9).  You will have to handle such requests manually.

The macro `Allocate` can be run as often as required.  You type some bookings into worksheet “New bookings” and run the macro.  The macro examines each booking from the list, allocates seat to it, removes the allocated seats from worksheet “Available”, adds the details of the allocation to worksheet “Allocated” and moved the processed booking to worksheet Processed.  Normally I would have handled all this in arrays but I thought it would be easier to code and understand if it operated off the worksheets.  The result of running my test data against my available is:

[image: Bookings after macro has been run]

Only bookings that cannot be processed remain in worksheet “New bookings”.  The reason a booking cannot be processed has been added.

[image: Available after the macro has been run]

Notice that rows A, B and so on have disappeared from Available because they have been allocated.

[image: Allocated after the macro has been run]

Worksheet “Allocated” is the source of any reports you need.  You could sort by name or seats to get different lists.  You could print tickets.  You could build an “auditorium” view of the bookings as you suggest in your question.

The two macros, `Allocate` and `Check`, are in separate answer because I have exceeded the character limit for an answer.

`Allocate` performs the allocate process described above.

`Check` validates the worksheets “Available” and “Allocated”.  `Allocate` updates four workbooks that must be kept in step.  An obscure error might mean that a seat is allocated twice or is lost from the system.  I have tested `Allocate` thoroughly but I cannot guarantee it is error free.  By running `Check` you will be able to detect the effect of any bugs immediately.

I suggest you test `Allocate` carefully.  Keep a copy of the bookings and the available seats in a worksheet not used by the macro.

If you encounter errors, you will probably have to send me a copy of your data.  See my profile for an email address.

The images above show the four worksheets used by the macros.  They are also fully explained within the macros.  Your posts are at 1:00 or 2:00 in the morning my time so I guess you are on west coast of the States.  Unfortunately, this just about maximises the turn round time for our communications.

Good luck with the macros.

Comment: This sounds just about perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225441/973283) for an explanation of this code.

This is a second posting.  I have made minor changes to macro `Allocate`.

```
Option Explicit

  ' Constants make the code more readable and make it easier to rearrange columns
  ' if necessary since changing the constant changes every use. If you had ever
  ' examined every 2 in a large block of code and had to decide if it was a reference
  ' to a particular column in a particular worksheet, you would understand why I use
  ' constants so heavily.

  ' Columns within worksheet "New bookings"
  Const ColNewBkFirst As Long = 1         ' This and ColNextLast allow columns to be
                                          ' rearranged at will.
  Const ColNewBkFamily As Long = 1
  Const ColNewBkGiven As Long = 2
  Const ColNewBkDay As Long = 3
  Const ColNewBkPart As Long = 4
  Const ColNewBkRequired As Long = 5
  Const ColNewBkError As Long = 6
  Const ColNewBkLast As Long = 5          ' Do not include error column
                                          ' which must be rightmost column

  ' Offsets within worksheet "Allocated"
  Const OffsetAllocFamily As Long = 0     ' \ Offsets on column found
  Const OffsetAllocGiven As Long = 1      ' | in header row to have
  Const OffsetAllocSeats As Long = 2      ' / required Day name

  ' First data rows in worksheets
  Const RowAllocDataFirst As Long = 3
  Const RowAvailDataFirst As Long = 3
  Const RowNewBkDataFirst As Long = 2
  Const RowProcDataFirst As Long = 2

  Const WidthAllocGroup As Long = 3     ' Number of columns for a Day
                                        ' in worksheet "Allocated"
Sub Allocate()

  ' * This macro updates 4 worksheets.  Excel does not provide the all
  '   updates of a block or none functionality of a database so the
  '   macro performs as many checks as it can to make sure that the
  '   four updates are all performed.
  ' * Errors in worksheet "New bookings" will result in an error
  '   message against the booking which will not have resulted in updates
  '   to the other worksheets.  Correct the error and rerun the macro.
  ' * Errors in worksheet "Available" are fatal. Any bookings already
  '   processed should be fine.  The booking that caused the error to be
  '   discovered will not have been processed.  Correct the error and
  '   rerun the macro.
  ' * Errors in worksheet "Allocated" will be reported as errors against
  '   the booking.  Correct the error and rerun the macro.
  ' * Processed bookings are moved to worksheet "Processed".  If you keep
  '   an original copy of worksheet "Available" then by replacing the
  '   updated "Available", copying the rows in "Processed" to
  '   "New bookings" and clearing "Allocated", you could restart the
  '   allocation process in the event of a disaster.
  ' * The four updates for a successfully processed booking are:
  '     - Booking deleted from "New bookings".
  '     - A range of available seats in "Available" will have been updated
  '       or deleted. For example a booking for 2 seats will replace "A3-A13"
  '       by "A5-A13" or will delete "A12-A13".
  '     - The customer's name and the seat range will have been added to
  '       "Allocated".
  '     - Booking added to "Processed"

  ' This stops odd seats being left at the end of seat ranges. Given the
  ' range "A11-A13", a booking for two seats would not be matched aginast it
  ' because if would leave one seat "A13". I do not think a value other
  ' than 2 would be sensible but I have not experimented. This rule is
  ' ignored if no other way of fulfilling a booking is found.
  Const MinSeatsInRange As Long = 2

  Dim Allocation As String
  Dim ColAllocCrnt As Long
  Dim ColAvailCrnt As Long
  Dim ErrorCrnt As String
  Dim FamilyNameCrnt As String
  Dim GivenNameCrnt As String
  Dim DayCrnt As String
  Dim NameAvailCol As String
  Dim PartCrnt As String
  Dim RequiredCrnt As Long
  Dim RowAllocNext As Long
  Dim RowAvailCrnt As Long
  Dim RowAvailLast As Long
  Dim RowAvailPoss As Long
  Dim RowNewBkCrnt As Long
  Dim RowProcNext As Long
  Dim SeatRange As String
  Dim SeatRangeRowCode As String
  Dim SeatRangeNumberFirst As Long
  Dim SeatRangeNumberLast As Long
  Dim SeatRangeCount As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' Without this the macro will be very slow

  ' Find next free row in worksheet "Processed"
  With Worksheets("Processed")
    RowProcNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNewBkFamily).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End With

  ' I cannot use a For-Loop for worksheet "New bookings" because I
  ' am deleting rows. The Do loop continues until it find a row
  ' with a blank family name.
  RowNewBkCrnt = RowNewBkDataFirst
  Do While True

    ' Copy booking to variables and perform internal checks.
    With Worksheets("New bookings")
      ErrorCrnt = ""        ' Ig nore any error message remainign from a previous run
      FamilyNameCrnt = .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkFamily).Value
      If FamilyNameCrnt = "" Then
        ' All new bookings processed
        Exit Do
      End If
      GivenNameCrnt = .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkGiven).Value
      DayCrnt = .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkDay).Value
      PartCrnt = .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkPart).Value
      If IsNumeric(.Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkRequired).Value) Then
        RequiredCrnt = .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkRequired).Value
        If RequiredCrnt < 1 Then
          ErrorCrnt = "Required must be 1 or more"
        End If
      Else
        ErrorCrnt = "Required not numeric"
      End If
    End With

    'Debug.Assert Not (DayCrnt = "Wednesday" And RequiredCrnt = 4)

    ' Find some seats that match the booking
    With Worksheets("Available")

      Allocation = ""
      RowAvailPoss = 0

      ' All following code is within "If ErrorCrnt = "" Then" to
      ' "End If" blocks. This means once an error is detected
      ' all other processing code is skipped.
      If ErrorCrnt = "" Then
        ' Find column for Day and Part
        ' Combine Day and Part to create column heading
        NameAvailCol = DayCrnt & _
                       IIf(PartCrnt <> "", " " & PartCrnt, "")
        ' Search along row 1 for expected column heading
        ColAvailCrnt = 1
        Do While True
          If .Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value = NameAvailCol Then
            ' Required column found
            Exit Do
          End If
          ColAvailCrnt = ColAvailCrnt + 1
          If .Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value = "" Then
            ' No matching column exists
            ErrorCrnt = "No column in worksheet Available has heading """ & _
                        NameAvailCol & """"
            Exit Do
          End If
        Loop
      End If  ' ErrorCrnt = ""

      ' Find range from which to allocate seats
      If ErrorCrnt = "" Then
        RowAvailLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAvailCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
        For RowAvailCrnt = RowAvailDataFirst To RowAvailLast
          SeatRange = .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Value
          ' Split seat range
          Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                               SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                               RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
          If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
            ' Fatal error
            Debug.Print ErrorCrnt
            Worksheets("Allocated").Activate
            Call MsgBox(ErrorCrnt, vbOKOnly)
            Exit Sub
          End If

          ' Compare booking against seat range
          If ErrorCrnt = "" Then
            If RequiredCrnt > SeatRangeCount Then
              ' This range is not big enough
            ElseIf RequiredCrnt = SeatRangeCount Then
              ' This range is exactly the right size
              ' Have leading zero because sort places "A1-A2" after "A11-A12" and
              ' "A1" after "A02-03"
              Allocation = SeatRangeRowCode & Right("0" & SeatRangeNumberFirst, 2)
              If RequiredCrnt > 1 Then
                Allocation = Allocation & "-" & SeatRangeRowCode & _
                               Right("0" & SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt - 1, 2)
              End If
              SeatRange = ""
            ElseIf SeatRangeCount - RequiredCrnt < MinSeatsInRange Then
              ' Removing this requirement from this range
              ' would leave too small a remainder
              If RowAvailPoss = 0 Then
                ' If no better means of fulfilling booking is found,
                ' this range will be accepted.
                RowAvailPoss = RowAvailCrnt
              End If
            Else
              ' Range is more than big enough. Record seat range allocated to booking
              ' and calculate reduced range to be written back to "Available".
              ' Have leading zeroes because sort places "A1-A2" after "A11-A12" and
              ' "A1" after "A02-03"
              Allocation = SeatRangeRowCode & Right("0" & SeatRangeNumberFirst, 2)
              If RequiredCrnt > 1 Then
                Allocation = Allocation & "-" & SeatRangeRowCode & _
                               Right("0" & SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt - 1, 2)
              End If
              SeatRange = SeatRangeRowCode & SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt
              If SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt < SeatRangeNumberLast Then
                SeatRange = SeatRange & "-" & SeatRangeRowCode & SeatRangeNumberLast
              End If
            End If
          End If

          If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
            Exit For
          End If
          If Allocation <> "" Then
            ' Required seats extracted from this range.
            ' Ignore remainder of Available column
            Exit For
          End If

        Next ' RowAvailCrnt
      End If  ' ErrorCrnt = ""

      If ErrorCrnt = "" Then
        If Allocation = "" Then
          If RowAvailPoss <> 0 Then
            ' A possible range was found but using it would have left an
            ' odd seat. Since nothing better has been found, use it
            RowAvailCrnt = RowAvailPoss
            SeatRange = .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Value

            ' Split seat range
            Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                                 SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                                 RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
            If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
              ' Fatal error.  Should not be possible since range already decoded
              Debug.Print ErrorCrnt
              Worksheets("Allocated").Activate
              Call MsgBox(ErrorCrnt, vbOKOnly)
              Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Know range is big enough so no need to check again
            ' Have leading zeroes because sort places "A1-A2" after "A11-A12" and
            ' "A1" after "A02-03"
            Allocation = SeatRangeRowCode & Right("0" & SeatRangeNumberFirst, 2)
            If RequiredCrnt > 1 Then
              Allocation = Allocation & "-" & SeatRangeRowCode & _
                                              SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt - 1
            End If
            SeatRange = SeatRangeRowCode & SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt
            If SeatRangeNumberFirst + RequiredCrnt < SeatRangeNumberLast Then
              SeatRange = SeatRange & "-" & SeatRangeRowCode & SeatRangeNumberLast
            End If
          Else
            ' No seat range big enough for RequiredCrnt was found
            ErrorCrnt = "No range was found big enough to allow allocation of " & _
                        RequiredCrnt & " seats"
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With

    If ErrorCrnt = "" Then

      ' Find appropriate column in worksheet "Allocated"
      With Worksheets("Allocated")
        ColAllocCrnt = 1
        Do While True
          If .Cells(1, ColAllocCrnt).Value = DayCrnt Then
            ' Required column found
            Exit Do
          End If
          ' Step to set of columns for next day
          ColAllocCrnt = ColAllocCrnt + WidthAllocGroup
          If .Cells(1, ColAllocCrnt).Value = "" Then
            ' No matching column exists
            'Debug.Assert False
            ErrorCrnt = "No column in worksheet Allocated has heading """ & DayCrnt & """"
            Exit Do
          End If
        Loop
      End With

    End If

    If ErrorCrnt = "" Then

      ' No errors found. Perform all updates for this booking.
      With Worksheets("Allocated")
        RowAllocNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAllocCrnt).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(RowAllocNext, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocFamily).Value = FamilyNameCrnt
        .Cells(RowAllocNext, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocGiven).Value = GivenNameCrnt
        .Cells(RowAllocNext, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocSeats).Value = Allocation
      End With
      With Worksheets("Available")
        If SeatRange = "" Then
          ' The range from which the allocate was made
          ' is now empty so delete it.
          .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
          ' Range not cleared.  Replaced old range with reduced range
          .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Value = SeatRange
        End If
      End With
      With Worksheets("New bookings")
        ' Copy processed booking to worksheet Processed
        .Range(.Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkFirst), .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkLast)).Copy _
                      Destination:=Worksheets("Processed").Cells(RowProcNext, 1)
        RowProcNext = RowProcNext + 1
        ' Delete processed booking
        .Rows(RowNewBkCrnt).EntireRow.Delete
      End With
      ' Note: No need to update RowNewBkCrnt because next row has moved up
     Else
      ' A non-fatal error has occurred.  Record it against the request.
      With Worksheets("New bookings")
        .Cells(RowNewBkCrnt, ColNewBkError).Value = ErrorCrnt
      End With
      RowNewBkCrnt = RowNewBkCrnt + 1  ' Update RowNextCrnt so this row is preserved
    End If

  Loop  ' Until all new booking processed or abandoned

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225441/973283) for an explanation of this code.

This is a second posting.  I have added another level of checking to macro `Check`.

```
Sub Check()

  ' Check there are no duplicate or missing seats.
  ' Report any errors found to the Immediate Window.

  Dim ColAllocCrnt As Long
  Dim ColAvailCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSeatCrnt As Long
  Dim DayCrnt As String
  Dim ErrorCount As Long
  Dim ErrorCrnt As String
  Dim RowAllocCrnt As Long
  Dim RowAllocLast As Long
  Dim RowAvailCrnt As Long
  Dim RowAvailLast As Long
  Dim RowSeatCrnt As Long
  Dim SeatNumberMax As Long
  Dim SeatRecorded() As String
  Dim SeatRecordedPart() As String
  Dim SeatRowCodeMax As String
  Dim SeatRowNumber As String
  Dim SeatRange As String
  Dim SeatRangeRowCode As String
  Dim SeatRangeNumberFirst As Long
  Dim SeatRangeNumberLast As Long
  Dim SeatRangeCount As Long

  ' Loop for each day recorded in worksheet "Available"
  ColAllocCrnt = 1
  Do While True

    With Worksheets("Allocated")
      If .Cells(1, ColAllocCrnt).Value = "" Then
        ' All days analysed
        Exit Do
      End If
      DayCrnt = .Cells(1, ColAllocCrnt).Value
    End With
    Debug.Print "Checking seats for " & DayCrnt

    ErrorCount = 0

    ' It it not possible to increase the number of columns in an array so
    ' scan worksheets "Allocated" and "Available" for maximum row code
    ' and seat number.

    SeatNumberMax = 0
    SeatRowCodeMax = ""

    With Worksheets("Allocated")
      ' ColAllocCrnt identifies the column for the current day

      ' Find maximum row code and seat letter in worksheet "Allocated"
      ' for current day
      RowAllocLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAllocCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      For RowAllocCrnt = RowAllocDataFirst To RowAllocLast
        SeatRange = .Cells(RowAllocCrnt, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocSeats).Value
        ' Split seat range
        Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                             SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                             RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
        If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
          Debug.Print ErrorCrnt
          ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        Else
          If SeatNumberMax < SeatRangeNumberLast Then
            ' Record new highest seat number
            SeatNumberMax = SeatRangeNumberLast
          End If
          If SeatRowCodeMax < SeatRangeRowCode Then
            ' Record new highest seat row code
            SeatRowCodeMax = SeatRangeRowCode
          End If
        End If
      Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("Available")

      ' There may be multiple columns in worksheet "Available" for the current day

      ColAvailCrnt = 1
      Do While True
        If .Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value = "" Then
          ' All columns in worksheet "Available" examined
          Exit Do
        End If
        If Left(.Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value, Len(DayCrnt)) = DayCrnt Then
          ' This column is for the current day

          ' Review SeatNumberMax and SeatRowCodeMax for available ranges
          RowAvailLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAvailCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
          For RowAvailCrnt = RowAvailDataFirst To RowAvailLast
            SeatRange = .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Value
            ' Split seat range
            Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                                 SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                                 RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
            If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
              Debug.Print ErrorCrnt
              ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
            Else
              If SeatNumberMax < SeatRangeNumberLast Then
                ' Record new highest seat number
                SeatNumberMax = SeatRangeNumberLast
              End If
              If SeatRowCodeMax < SeatRangeRowCode Then
                ' Record new highest seat row code
                SeatRowCodeMax = SeatRangeRowCode
              End If
            End If
          Next
        End If
        ColAvailCrnt = ColAvailCrnt + 1
      Loop
    End With

    Debug.Print "  " & SeatRowCodeMax & SeatNumberMax

    SeatRowNumber = Asc(SeatRowCodeMax) - Asc("A") + 1

    ' Size array so there is room for every possible seat
    ' Note: cells will be initialised to empty
    ReDim RowSeatRecorded(1 To SeatNumberMax, 1 To SeatRowNumber)

    ' * Record workssheet, row and column on which each seat is recorded.
    '   Format is X:Row:Col where X is L for "Allocated" and V for "Available".
    ' * No seat should be recorded more than once.  Report any duplicates.

    With Worksheets("Allocated")

      RowAllocLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAllocCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      For RowAllocCrnt = RowAllocDataFirst To RowAllocLast
        SeatRange = .Cells(RowAllocCrnt, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocSeats).Value
        ' Split seat range
        Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                             SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                             RowAllocCrnt, ColAllocCrnt)
        If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
          ' Error already reported
        Else
          SeatRowNumber = Asc(SeatRangeRowCode) - Asc("A") + 1
          For ColSeatCrnt = SeatRangeNumberFirst To SeatRangeNumberLast
            If RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber) = 0 Then
              ' First occurrence of this seat number
              RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber) = _
                                "L:" & RowAllocCrnt & ":" & ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocSeats
            Else
              ' Duplicate recording of seat
              Debug.Print "  " & GenDuplicateSeatError(SeatRangeRowCode & ColSeatCrnt, _
                                RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber), "L", _
                                RowAllocCrnt, ColAllocCrnt + OffsetAllocSeats)
              ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("Available")

      ' There may be multiple columns in worksheet "Available" for the current day

      ColAvailCrnt = 1
      Do While True
        If .Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value = "" Then
          ' All columns in worksheet "Available" examined
          Exit Do
        End If
        If Left(.Cells(1, ColAvailCrnt).Value, Len(DayCrnt)) = DayCrnt Then
          ' This column is for the current day

          RowAvailLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColAvailCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
          For RowAvailCrnt = RowAvailDataFirst To RowAvailLast
            SeatRange = .Cells(RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt).Value
            ' Split seat range
            Call DecodeSeatRange(SeatRange, SeatRangeRowCode, SeatRangeNumberFirst, _
                                 SeatRangeNumberLast, SeatRangeCount, ErrorCrnt, _
                                 RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
            If ErrorCrnt <> "" Then
              ' Already reported
            Else
              SeatRowNumber = Asc(SeatRangeRowCode) - Asc("A") + 1
              For ColSeatCrnt = SeatRangeNumberFirst To SeatRangeNumberLast
                If RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber) = 0 Then
                  ' First occurrence of this seat number
                  RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber) = "V:" & RowAvailCrnt & ":" & ColAvailCrnt
                Else
                  ' Duplicate recording of seat
                  Debug.Print "  " & GenDuplicateSeatError(SeatRangeRowCode & ColSeatCrnt, _
                                    RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, SeatRowNumber), "V", _
                                    RowAvailCrnt, ColAvailCrnt)
                  ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
                End If
              Next
            End If
          Next
        End If
        ColAvailCrnt = ColAvailCrnt + 1
      Loop
    End With

    ' Look for gaps in the array of seats.
    For RowSeatCrnt = 1 To UBound(RowSeatRecorded, 2)

      ' Scan for recorded seat
      For ColSeatCrnt = UBound(RowSeatRecorded, 1) To 1 Step -1
        If RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, RowSeatCrnt) <> "" Then
          ' This seat recorded
          Exit For
        End If
      Next

      ' Scan for gap between last recorded seat and first
      For ColSeatCrnt = ColSeatCrnt - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If RowSeatRecorded(ColSeatCrnt, RowSeatCrnt) = "" Then
          Debug.Print "  Seat " & Chr(RowSeatCrnt + 64) & ColSeatCrnt & " not found"
          ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        End If
      Next

    Next

    Debug.Print "  " & ErrorCount & " errors found"

    ColAllocCrnt = ColAllocCrnt + WidthAllocGroup

  Loop  ' For each day in worksheet "Allocated

End Sub


Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = Code

End Function
Sub DecodeSeatRange(ByVal SeatRange As String, ByRef RowCode As String, _
                    ByRef NumberFirst As Long, ByRef NumberLast As Long, _
                    ByRef Count As Long, ByRef ErrorMsg As String, _
                    ByVal RowAvail As Long, ByVal ColAvail As Long)

  ' * Split a seat range into it components.
  ' * A seat range is:
  '      RowCode Number
  '   or RowCode Number - RowCode Number
  ' * The two RowCodes must be the same.
  ' * The numbers must be one or more and Last cannot be less than First
  ' * If ErrorMsg = "" or return, the seat range has been successfully
  '   decoded.  Otherwise it reports the error found.

  Dim RangePart() As String

  RangePart = Split(SeatRange, "-")
  If UBound(RangePart) = 0 Then
    ' Have single seat range.
    ' Extract seat details into variables and perform internal checks
    RowCode = Mid(SeatRange, 1, 1)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(SeatRange, 2)) Then
      NumberFirst = Mid(SeatRange, 2)
      NumberLast = NumberFirst
      Count = 1
    Else
      ErrorMsg = "Seat number is not numeric"
    End If
  Else
    ' Have normal seat range; Xn-Ym.
    ' Split range details into variables and perform internal checks
    RowCode = Mid(RangePart(0), 1, 1)
    If RowCode <> Mid(RangePart(1), 1, 1) Then
      ErrorMsg = "Fatal error in worksheet ""Available"". Range in cell " & _
                  ColNumToCode(ColAvail) & RowAvail & " is not a single row"
    Else
      If Not IsNumeric(Mid(RangePart(0), 2)) Then
        ErrorMsg = "Fatal error in worksheet Available. Start of range in cell " & _
                   ColNumToCode(ColAvail) & RowAvail & _
                   "  is not <RowCode><Number>"
      Else
        NumberFirst = Mid(RangePart(0), 2)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(RangePart(1), 2)) Then
          ErrorMsg = "Fatal error in worksheet Available. End of range in cell " & _
                     ColNumToCode(ColAvail) & RowAvail & _
                     "  is not <RowCode><Number>"
        Else
          NumberLast = Mid(RangePart(1), 2)
          Count = NumberLast - NumberFirst + 1
          If Count > 0 Then
            ' Good range
          Else
            ' Bad range
            ErrorMsg = "Fatal error in worksheet Available. " & _
                        "Start of range after end of range cell " & _
                        ColNumToCode(ColAvail) & RowAvail
          End If
        End If
     End If
   End If
  End If  ' single seat/multiple seat range

End Sub
Function GenDuplicateSeatError(ByVal Seat As String, ByVal Record As String, _
                               ByVal WshtCode As String, ByVal RowCrnt As Long, _
                               ByVal ColCrnt As Long) As String

  ' * Record contained details of a previous encounter of a seat.  Its format is
  '   X:Row:Column where X is "L" for worksheet "Allocated" or "V" for worksheet
  '   "Available".
  ' * WshtCode, RowCrnt and ColCrnt identify a second or subsequent encounter
  '   of the seat.  Generate a suitable error message.

  Dim RecordPart() As String

  RecordPart = Split(Record, ":")

  GenDuplicateSeatError = "Seat " & Seat & " is recorded in " & _
                          IIf(RecordPart(0) = "L", "Allocated", "Available") & "." & _
                          ColNumToCode(Val(RecordPart(2))) & RecordPart(1) & " and " & _
                          IIf(WshtCode = "L", "Allocated", "Available") & "." & _
                          ColNumToCode(ColCrnt) & RowCrnt

End Function
```

Comment: Just spent a while testing this and it's fantastic! Really cannot thank you enough. To comment on the fact that I'm posting at 1am, I'm a student, we have a horrible habit of not sleeping. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @Avg  I am pleased you like it.  I am way over Stack Overflow's character limit for an answer so I do not want to add any more code.  However, I have two more macros.  One prints a list in either name or seat sequence.  The other prints the Auditorium view you were originally creating.  If you want them, send an email to the address in my profile.

Comment: @Avg I haven't been a student for 46 years and my youngest child hasn't been a student for 10 years so I had forgotten about strange sleeping patterns. If you are not West Coast USA, where are you?